# OnCreateView in fragment is only called the first time and never again

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am building an app mostly using a single activity and fragments for everything I do inside it.
On my MainActivity, I handle the creation of a drawer menu where I have items that going to Fragments when I tap. When I open the app, it works fine, I switch to another fragment and that also works fine but when I go back to the original fragment, I see the UI but no data being displayed. I have come to the conclusion that the Fragments displaying my content are not created and the debugger doesn't hit any breakpoints so I assume I am right.

`MainActivity.java`

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment).commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_user_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, userFragment).commit();
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_user_profile);
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
);
```

`HomeFragment.java`

```
homeFragments = new ArrayList<>();
homeFragments.add(newPostFragment("/...", "/..."));
homeFragments.add(newPostFragment("/...", "/..."));
```

Where `newPostFragment` is

```
private PostFragment newPostFragment(String /..., String /...) {
    PostFragment fragment = new PostFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("/...", /...);
    args.putString("/...", /...);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And finally, `PostFragment.java`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Post", "onViewCreated: Called");
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mToken = InjectorUtils.getInstance().provideTokenRepository(getActivity().getApplication()).getToken();
    /... = getArguments().getInt("/...", 0);
    /... = getArguments().getString("/...", "");
    /... = getArguments().getString("/...", "");
    initRecycleView();
    initializeUI();
}
```

I can't see the reason why this is not working since it has no issues whatsoever when I first open the app. I am also using LiveData and cache the result in the viewmodel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: me familiar issue if you know kindly give me answer my fab button not hide and extension fab button not shrink you can see my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259818/adapter-not-found-skipped-in-fragment-with-navigation-drawer-and-appbar

Comment: Don't not use .beginTransaction().replace, instead of this use "add" and "addToBackStack" like - getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_between, homeFragment, HomeFragment.TAG)
                .addToBackStack(HomeFragment.TAG).commit();

Comment: @SanwalSingh I use replace to put another layout in the place of a FrameLayout placeholder I have set in my `activity_main.xml`. What is this `.TAG` you're using?

Comment: TAG is static string inside Fragment like -  public static String TAG = "Home Fragment";

Comment: I used this and it keeps the fragment I want alive but I don't really want to have the user fragment in memory. Since the user fragment has fragments in it, do I need to destroy them in `onDestroy` of the user fragment? @SanwalSingh

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the previously created instance of your Fragments, try to use "onResume" to synchronise the view and the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call again onCreateView() just re attach the fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commitNow()
getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commitNow()
```